# My SQL says it's running but it doesn't connect

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

When I check mySQL it tells me it's running.

I had this problem before and I fixed it with the line:

```
mysql -u root
```

But now it doesn't work anymore. The problem is that I had installed mySQL one time before, and when I deleted it from my computer something probably went wrong. When I type in the command it tells me:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I don't have a password set up. Maybe someone can help me? Perhaps I have to delete mySQL completely from my harddrive and re-install everything again?

Maybe someone can guide me through the steps how to completely 100% re-install mysql to get it working properly again? Or tell me what's wrong with the command?

I don't have a password set.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you dont have 2 instances of MYSQL installed and you have started the old one that did have a password set on the `root` account

Comment: I don't have a password set. I have deleted the other mySQL, but maybe not properly enough.